# openSSL edit email address max value

Tags: email, openssl

Is it ok if i edit emailAddress_max value in openssl.cnf file. The default value is 64. But i want to change to 129 for my project. In my project the max length of email address is 129(local is 64 @ domain is 64).
I want to know is there any reason for the default max 64 value?

thank you.